# Create macro for where condition in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset which has more than 150+ names. Example - A1,B1,C1,…so on.

I have a code using which I'm getting sales for each name, right now I'm running the following query by selecting names manually.

```
create table want as 
select Name
,sum(sales) as sales
from have
where name in ('A1','B1')
group by Name
;quit;
```

I want to run this code in such a way that it picks one name from the list at a time and stores the results in a dataset then picks another name and stores in another dataset and so on. At the end appends all the 150+ datasets into one final dataset. Please help me do this. Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to make one dataset in the end why make the 150 individual ones first?

Comment: If you're running into performance issues, try proc means instead. doing this via macro doesn't seem efficient at all.

Comment: If you just delete `where name in ('A1','B1')` from your example program, could you get what you want? Or you just want to learn how to do it step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your names are stored in a single dataset that looks as follows:

```
name
A1
B1
C1 
...
```

I'm going to assume that there could be duplicates of each one. We'll remove those duplicates, run a data step from `call execute()` to dynamically generate SQL for each name, then append each dataset to a single dataset at the end.

```
proc sort data=have(keep=name) out=names nodupkey;
    by name;
run;

data _null_;
    set names;

    call execute(cat(
     'proc sql;',
     '    create table tmp_', _N_, ' as',
     '        select name, sum(sales) as sales',
     '        from have',
     '        where name=', quote(name),
     '        group by name;',
     'quit;')
    );
run;

data want;
    set tmp_:;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Stu. I have an aggregation in my query, how can I incorporate that group by here. Please let me know.

Comment: I have updated it to use SQL for aggregation instead.